# edit TextView in child view in ExpandableListView android

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

i have Expandable List View android when change my Text view `txtChild.Text = "some Words...";` after clicking button in the same child view ,, last child only editing in all parent  !!
i want the child position clicked only change not the last child ?
how do that ?

this is my ExpandableListAdapter class

`
    class ExpandableListAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter
    {
        TextView txtListChild;

```
    private Activity _context;

    private List<string> _listDataHeader; // header titles

    // child data in format of header title, child title

    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _listDataChild;





    public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity activity, List<string> listDataHeader, Dictionary<String, List<string>> listChildData)
    {
        this._context = activity;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }


    public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return _listDataChild[_listDataHeader[groupPosition]][childPosition];
    }


    public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }


    public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        string childText = (string)GetChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListItemCustomLayout, null);
           txtListChild = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.lListItem);
              Button CollectAll = (Button)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.button1);

              CollectAll.Click += delegate
              {
                  txtListChild.Text = "some words ..";
                 // i want child  position clicked only text  changed 

              }; 
        }


        txtListChild.Text = childText;
        return convertView;
    }




    public override int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return _listDataChild[_listDataHeader[groupPosition]].Count;
    }


    public override Java.Lang.Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return _listDataHeader[groupPosition];
    }


    public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }


    public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        string headerTitle = (string)GetGroup(groupPosition);

        convertView = convertView ?? _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.HeaderCustomLayout, null);
        var lblListHeader = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.lListHeader);
        lblListHeader.Text = headerTitle;

        return convertView;
    }


    public override int GroupCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _listDataHeader.Count;
        }
    }


    public override bool HasStableIds
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }

}`
```

and this my activity

```
 public class layout1 : Activity
{
    Sqlitedb db = new Sqlitedb();
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;

    List<string> listDataHeader;
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> listDataChild;
    int previousGroup = -1;

      protected  override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

        // Create your application here
        expListView = FindViewById<ExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.vExp);

        //// Prepare list data
         prepareListData();

        //Bind list
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        expListView.SetAdapter(listAdapter);

        FnClickEvents();




    }



      void prepareListData()
      {
          listDataHeader = new List<String>();
          listDataChild = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();

          // Adding child data
          listDataHeader.Add("Top 250");
          listDataHeader.Add("Now Showing");
          listDataHeader.Add("Coming Soon..");

          // Adding child data
          List<String> top250 = new List<String>();
          top250.Add("The Shawshank Redemption");
          top250.Add("The Godfather");
          top250.Add("The Godfather: Part II");
          top250.Add("Pulp Fiction");
          top250.Add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
          top250.Add("The Dark Knight");
          top250.Add("12 Angry Men");

          List<String> nowShowing = new List<String>();
          nowShowing.Add("The Conjuring");
          nowShowing.Add("Despicable Me 2");
          nowShowing.Add("Turbo");
          nowShowing.Add("Grown Ups 2");
          nowShowing.Add("Red 2");
          nowShowing.Add("The Wolverine");

          List<String> comingSoon = new List<String>();
          comingSoon.Add("2 Guns");
          comingSoon.Add("The Smurfs 2");
          comingSoon.Add("The Spectacular Now");
          comingSoon.Add("The Canyons");
          comingSoon.Add("Europa Report");

          // Header, Child data


          listDataChild.Add(listDataHeader[0], top250);
          listDataChild.Add(listDataHeader[1], nowShowing);
          listDataChild.Add(listDataHeader[2], comingSoon);
          //RunOnUiThread(() =>
          //{
          //    listDataChild.Remove("Top 250");
          //    listAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();


          //});

      }







         void FnClickEvents()
    {
        //Listening to child item selection
        expListView.ChildClick += delegate(object sender, ExpandableListView.ChildClickEventArgs e)
        {

           // listDataChild.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
            Toast.MakeText(this, "child", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        };

        //Listening to group expand
        //modified so that on selection of one group other opened group has been closed
        expListView.GroupExpand += delegate(object sender, ExpandableListView.GroupExpandEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.GroupPosition != previousGroup)
                expListView.CollapseGroup(previousGroup);
            previousGroup = e.GroupPosition;
        };

        //Listening to group collapse
        expListView.GroupCollapse += delegate(object sender, ExpandableListView.GroupCollapseEventArgs e)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "group", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }; 
    }



}
```

Comment: Please Post your codes, so that we can help you fix it.

Comment: I edit it please  help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have Expandable List View android when change my Text view txtChild.Text = "some Words..."; after clicking button in the same child view ,, last child only editing in all parent !!

It's because you store the `txtChild` globally like below:

```
class ExpandableListAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter { 
    TextView txtListChild;
    ...
    public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
       ...
       txtListChild = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.lListItem);
       ...
    }
    txtListChild.Text = childText;
    return convertView;
}
```

So when the children views get rendered. `GetChildView` get called for several times and `txtListChild` points to the last child view.

To fix the problem you simply need to move the declaration `TextView txtListChild` to inside the method `GetChildView` like below:

```
class ExpandableListAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter { 
    ...
    public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
       TextView txtListChild;
       ...
       txtListChild = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.lListItem);
       ...
       txtListChild.Text = childText;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: it solved :) ,, thanks very much for help :) @Elvis Xia - MSFT